# NextJS, Prisma does't automatically fetch data from database in production, generate static pages?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, prisma

I didn't enable any SSG option. Everything is okay in development, however, when I deploy my project, my application only fetch data once from database then any change in database it won't fetch.
When I deploy my app, it said that "generate static pages" and fetch data. How is it possible?
[It said that generate static pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dsu7.png)

I tried redeploy my app, every time it fetch data and generate static page.